# How to return the cv::Mat Data when I extend C++ using the distutils

Tags: c++, python-3.x, opencv, extend, distutils

I want to use a Open CV code writing by C++ as a python library.

But I cant find the way return cv::Mat data when I use distutils for wrapping.

cv_convarter.cpp

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

static PyObject* cv_imread(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    cv::Mat img;

    img = cv::imread("sample.png", 1);

    //if(img.empty()) return -1;

    // Py_RETURN_NONE;

    // How to return array or cv::Mat or numpy
    //return img;
};


static PyMethodDef cv_convarter_methods[] = {
    {
        "cv_imread", 
        cv_imread, METH_NOARGS,
        "output cv imread array."
    },
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef cv_convarter_definition = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "cv_convarter",
    "CV Convarter Sample.",
    -1,
    cv_convarter_methods
};


PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_cv_convarter(void){
    Py_Initialize();
    return PyModule_Create(&cv_convarter_definition);
}
```

setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8

from distutils.core import setup, Extension

cv_convarter_module = Extension(
      'cv_convarter',
      include_dirs=['/usr/include/python3.4'],
      extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11'],
      sources=['cv_convarter.cpp']
)

setup(
      name='cv_converter',
      version='0.1.0',
      description='example opencv c++ convert python library',
      ext_modules=[cv_convarter_module]
)
```

then,

```
python3 setup.py build
```

I can get

```
cv_convarter.cpython-34m.so
```

But I cant import this library and I get the error message.

```
ImportError: Pathofsofile/cv_convarter.cpython-34m.so: 
undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3Mat10deallocateEv
```

How to write the extending code that return a cv::Mat data.

Comment: I will try using the Boost.Python way.

Comment: I find it.https://github.com/spillai/numpy-opencv-converter